# Syntax error near unexpected token "(", indirect expansion variable declaration

Tags: bash, syntax, token, seq

In BASH,

I should note that the variables $Lambda0_List etc, are read from an input file earlier in the code.

> ```
> PARAM_ARRAY=("Lambda0" "N" "M" "Sigma")
>
> for i in "${PARAM_ARRAY[@]}"
>
> do
>
>  List="$i"_List
>
>  Vary="$i"_Vary
>
>  Use_Range="$i"_Use_Range
>
>  Initial_Str="$i"_Initial
>
>  Final_Str="$i"_Final
>
>  Step_Str="$i"_Step
>
>  Initial=${!Initial_Str}
>
>  Step=${!Step_Str}
>
>  Final=${!Final_Str}
>
>  if [ "${!Vary}" ==  "T" ] 
>
>  then
>
>   if [ "${!Use_Range}" == "T" ]
>
>   then 
>
>    eval "$List=(`seq $Initial $Step $Final `)"
>
>    echo "$i : vary, use_range" 
>
>   else
>
>    echo "$i: vary, use list"
>
>   fi
>
>  fi
>
> done
> ```

Throws a syntax error

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

Normally I'm able to interpret the error and find a solution, but I don't understand why the "(" is an unexpected token.

edit:

I've noticed that this line works if I run it in shell, but not in my script,

edit:

Fiddling around with the problematic line, I found that I get a syntax error even when its commented out!

> /test.sh: line 266: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> ./test.sh: line 266:  `########    eval "$List=(`seq $Initial $Step $Final `)"'

Comment: What are the values of the variables?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the variable assignments.
although the capital I's look different than in the eval statement, they are typed the same in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sifting through some earlier code, I fixed some issue with ' vs ", and this error stopped coming.  I'm new to BASH so I didn't expect that an error message with ')' to be caused by a quote 100 lines above.

Answer (score 0):

After !Final you have a ) instead of a }

Comment: that was a typo in submitting the question, I've fixed it here.

I've tried shuffling the variable names around so I don't need the indirect expansion, so it looks like:

eval "$List=(``seq $Initial $Step $Final ` ` )",

and again, it works in terminal but not in the script.

Comment: Can you paste in the actual code you are using rather than typing it up? Who knows what other errors might be in the original script

Answer (score 0):

why dont use elif or case ?

eval "$List=(`seq $Initial $Step $Final`)"

instead of

eval "${List=(`seq $Initial $Step $Final`)}" or eval "${List=`seq $Initial $Step $Final`}"